# Facing problem of "''block block-block-content block-block-contente1ace621-3e0d-4b51-848d-aa830cd4a1c5"'' while web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am writing a Python **scraper** for this [website](https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/browse-meetings/2019%20Oncology%20Practice%20Conference?presentationList=0%7C1%7C0):

I am trying to grab the below CSS:

```
<div _ngcontent-ail-c10="" class="inner"><!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": "2019-09-05T14:30:00Z"
    }--><div _ngcontent-ail-c10="" class="session-date ng-tns-c10-3 ng-star-inserted"><span _ngcontent- 
   ail-c10="" class="date-day">Thursday, September 5</span><span _ngcontent-ail-c10="" class="date- 
   time"><span _ngcontent-ail-c10="" class="date-time-start">2:30 PM</span><!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": "2019-09-05T16:00:00Z"
    }--><span _ngcontent-ail-c10="" class="date-time-end ng-tns-c10-3 ng-star-inserted"> - 4:00 
    PM</span></span></div><!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": "Sapphire Ballroom C, Level 4"
    }--><div _ngcontent-ail-c10="" class="session-location ng-tns-c10-3 ng-star-inserted"><strong 
    _ngcontent-ail-c10="" class="ng-tns-c10-3">Location:</strong> Sapphire Ballroom C, Level 4 </div><!- 
   -bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": "General Session"
    }--><div _ngcontent-ail-c10="" class="session-type ng-tns-c10-3 ng-star-inserted"> General Session 
    </div><!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": "General Session"
    }--><div _ngcontent-ail-c10="" class="session-title ng-tns-c10-3 ng-star-inserted"><!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true",
      "ng-reflect-ng-if-else": "[object Object]"
    }--><a _ngcontent-ail-c10="" class="ng-tns-c10-3 ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-router- 
   link="/session,12137" href="/session/12137">Considerations in Value-Based Contracting</a><!----> 
   </div><!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
    }--><div _ngcontent-ail-c10="" class="session-tracks ng-tns-c10-3 ng-star-inserted"><strong 
    _ngcontent-ail-c10="" class="ng-tns-c10-3">Track(s): </strong><!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "Education Track"
    }--><span _ngcontent-ail-c10="" class="ng-tns-c10-3 ng-star-inserted">Education Track<!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
    }--></span></div><!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
    }--><div _ngcontent-ail-c10="" class="session-chair ng-tns-c10-3 ng-star-inserted"><strong 
    _ngcontent-ail-c10="" class="ng-tns-c10-3">Chair(s): </strong><!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "Linda D. Bosserman, MD, FACP, "
    }--><span _ngcontent-ail-c10="" class="ng-tns-c10-3 ng-star-inserted">Linda D. Bosserman, MD, FACP, 
    FASCO | City of Hope<!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
    }--><span _ngcontent-ail-c10="" class="ng-tns-c10-3 ng-star-inserted">; </span></span><span 
    _ngcontent-ail-c10="" class="ng-tns-c10-3 ng-star-inserted">Barry Russo, MBA | The Center for Cancer 
    and Blood Disorders<!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
    }--></span></div><!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": "1.5"
    }--><div _ngcontent-ail-c10="" class="session-credit ng-tns-c10-3 ng-star-inserted"><strong 
    _ngcontent-ail-c10="" class="ng-tns-c10-3">Attendee CE/MOC Credit: </strong><span _ngcontent-ail- 
   c10="" class="ng-tns-c10-3">1.5</span></div><!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
     }--><a _ngcontent-ail-c10="" class="get-presentations ng-tns-c10-3 ng-star-inserted" href="#" ng- 
   reflect-klass="get-presentations" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">View Presentation<!-- 
    bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
    }--><span _ngcontent-ail-c10="" class="ng-tns-c10-3 ng-star-inserted">s</span></a><!--bindings={}--> 
    </div>
```

I am using the following code snippet:

```
   my_url = 'https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/browse- 
   meetings/2019%20Gastrointestinal%20Cancers%20Symposium'
    uclient = uReq(my_url)
    page_html = uclient.read()
    uclient.close()
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
    containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"inner"})
```

But it is taking stuff off the website which says "Blocked Content".

Answer (score 0):

The Page is rendered via `JavaScript`, I've been able to locate the `XHR` request from where the data is rendered.

Now you do have a dictionary. do whatever you want .

```
import requests

r = requests.get(
    "https://cdn-solr.asco.org/solr/ml/mlselect?_format=json&wt=json&indent=true&q=*&start=0&rows=30&sort=ISODateString%20asc,%20ISODateStringEnd%20asc,%20SessionType%20asc,%20SessionId%20asc&fq=-SessionType:%22Pre-Annual%20Meeting%20Seminar%22%20AND%20RecordType:sessions%20AND%20Meeting:%222019%20Oncology%20Practice%20Conference%22&fq={!tag=date}ISODateString:[*%20TO%20*]&fq=public_b:true&facet=true&f.Year.facet.sort=index&facet.field={!key=Year}Year&facet.field={!key=subject_thes}subject_thes&facet.field={!key=MediaTypes}MediaTypes&facet.field={!key=fctSessionType}fctSessionType&facet.pivot={!key=MeetingName}fctMeetingName,fctTrack&spellcheck.maxCollationTries=100").json()

print(r)
```

Comment: It is indeed working, but how to clean the resultant data, because it is picking up almost everything that is there in the page.